# Playing Video Files in Windows Forms with MediaPlayer

Tags: c#, video, windows-forms

With the following encoding, only the audio part of the video is played, but the video itself is not shown:

```
mediaPlayer = new Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer()
{
   AutoPlay = true,
   Source = Windows.Media.Core.MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(DialogFileName)),
};
```

Who knows advice?
Thanks for that!

Comment: Windows Forms is not a common game development technology, so you may find better answers to this on StackOverflow.

Comment: What type of file are you trying to play? Are you able to play the file manually?